# Add columns of old purchases per customer to compare them

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

Reading a book on Sqlite and decided to test certain queries for fun.

This one got me thinking.

How would you return the number of the continuous buyers who got a new item with a lower price than their previous item?

- no joins required its all in the same table.
- relevant table names: `day`: date bought ,`customer`, `price`

So far i have located the continuous customers but can't do the check of their previous purchase.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTOMER HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Thinking that by adding each customer's purchase in a column next to each other, ordered by `date_bought` is maybe the only way to do an actual 'per continuous customer' check.

For reproducibillity you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    day DATE,
    price FLOAT
    item char
    customer char
);

INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-2 day'), 0.5,'food','Jenny');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-23 day'), 1,'food','Jenny');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-1 day'), 11,'food','Betty');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-22 day'), 7,'food','Betty');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-3 day'), 8,'food','Katy');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-4 day'), 10,'food','Mary');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-23 day'), 1,'food','Mary');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-1 day'), 2,'food','Anna');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-2 day'), 12,'food','Anna');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-3 day'), 8,'food','Anna');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-4 day'), 10,'food','Lisa');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-5 day'), 5,'food','Lisa');
INSERT INTO orders(day, price,item,customer) VALUES(date('now', 'localtime', '-8 day'), 12,'food','Jenny');
```

Comment: When you say no joins are allowed, does that include self joins?

Comment: i didn't say that, i said they are just in the same table. self joins are probably the path to solution but was difficult to do them right

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the count and don't care about who the specific customers are then one way to get the count of customers who ordered the same item more than once, and for a lower price at the later time, is to use a correlated subquery with the `exists` predicate:

```
select count(distinct customer) 
from orders o1
where exists (
    select customer 
    from orders o2 
    where o1.customer = o2.customer and 
          o1.item = o2.item and 
          o1.day > o2.day and 
          o1.price < o2.price
    );
```

This returns the count of distinct customers for which there exists a row with the same item and a higher price at an earlier day.

If I understood your question I think this is what you want.

Comment: How would you make it faster by choosing to do what you wrote only on the already continuous customers? for example using my select statement : `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTOMER HAVING COUNT(*)>1);` somewhere, so it doesn't have to check **all** the customers in the database?

Comment: I'm not really sure I can make it faster (if that really is an issue) as any solution to this problem would involve checking one set against another in order to find the ones with matching customer and item and different date and price properties.
Given proper indices this should execute as fast as any other solution.
If you have a very large dataset I guess you could preprocess it to remove rows with customers who didn't order the same item repeatedly, but in the normal case this would probably be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: this is exactly what i was talking about.More like filtering before you do that.given a huge dataset with most of them one time buyers how would i preprocess that?

Comment: I would do like you suggested and filter out non-repeat customers first and use the remaining set as the source for query. Something like this perhaps: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17371

Answer (score 0):

My self join approach would be something like this.

```
select your field
from orders o1 join orders o2 on o1.customer = o2.customer

where o2.price < o1.price
and o1.day = (select max(day)
from orders
where day < o2.day
and customer = o2.customer)
```

That's assuming that `their previous item` refers to an item on their most recent order.  If `their previous item` refers to any previous order, you can replace the subquery with:

```
and o1.day < o2.day
```

Comment: How would you make it faster by choosing to do what you wrote only on the already continuous customers? for example using my select statement : `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTOMER HAVING COUNT(*)>1); `somewhere, so it doesn't have to check **all** the customers in the database?

Comment: I wouldn't.  First, it's not necessary and second, it wouldn't necessarily improve performance.

Comment: if you have 1 million rows don't you think it's better to filter only the continuous customers in the query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE.  This will give you the actual details.  If you want just the count simply replace the final `SELECT *` with `SELECT COUNT(*)`:

```
with xxx(day,price,item,customer,previous_price,previous_date) as (
  select *,null,null from orders group by customer having min(day)
  union all
  select o.day,o.price,o.item,o.customer,x.price,x.day
    from orders o join xxx x using(customer)
    where o.price < x.price
      and o.day > x.day
  )
  select * from xxx
    where previous_price is not null;
```

If looking in comparison to immediately previous purchase, then this alternative:

```
with xxx(day,price,item,customer,previous_price,previous_date) as (
  select *,null,null from orders
  union all
  select o.day,o.price,o.item,o.customer,x.price,x.day
    from orders o join xxx x using(customer)
    where o.price < x.price
      and o.day > x.day
  )
  select * from xxx group by customer having max(previous_date);
```

Comment: Although the names are correct the old price and last price of the corresponding names are not true check it out

Comment: As it wasn't completely clear whether you want the purchase immediately before the last one or any previous one, I have assumed any previous purchase by that customer.  In that sense, it is correct.  Can you provide your expected correct result?  I will update the query accordingly.

Comment: How would you make it faster by choosing to do what you wrote only on the already continuous customers? for example using my select statement : `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTOMER HAVING COUNT(*)>1); `somewhere, so it doesn't have to check ** all** the customers in the database?

Comment: "so it doesn't have to check ** all** the customers in the database?": One way or another all rows (be it directly or via corresponding indices) will have to be checked against some condition(s), or else how are you going to have a valid result? (BTW, your outer `select` is superfluous.)  Do you think your `select` magically skips rows to come up with a right answer?  Optimization comes after you've got a correct result. Get to that first, and then worry about fine tuning your approach.  Your statement wrongly assumes that your `select` somehow does the whole job easier. Well, it doesn't!

Comment: actually my select was an example to you to understand my point of dealing with huge datasets where most are one time buyers. How would you filter those out to do the process faster.